# Colouring a map with unknown regions

Tags: general-topology

When colouring a map with known regions, a maximum of four colours are required.

How many colours are required when the regions are unknown?

The use-case I have in mind is in puzzles where you construct the regions as the puzzle progresses. Given that you don't know how many regions there are, and how they're arranged, how many colours do you need to use to guarantee connecting regions are different colours?

Two dimensional maps only.

Edits:

Newly discovered regions may be isolated from previously discovered regions.

Newly discovered regions may grow as new clues are discovered. Example of such a puzzle: https://youtu.be/emH5qSvPTes

Regions are not always constrained to be the same size

Regions are often constructed on an orthoganal grid, so no infinitesimals.

The grid is almost always finite, but periodic boundary conditions sometimes apply (eg https://youtu.be/xRoCWkm_8KE), although this is a special case.

Comment: When a new region arises is it always adjacent to a pre-existing region, or might it be isolated?  I take it that we must decide on the color of each region before seeing the next region, and that once we have colored it, we cannot change.  Correct?

Comment: @saulspatz your last statement is correct. I think that a new region could be isolated, but we (you?) can assume adjacent if it makes life easier.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this; I'm just trying to understand the problem.  I notice you say "maps" not "graphs".  With a map, it's possible that we would know a region cannot be adjacent to some future region, because it's completely surrounded.  I don't see how an analogous thing could be true of a graph.  But once you you have maps, four colors don't necessarily suffice without some restriction on the nature of the regions.  See https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647828?seq=1